How to run .jsx in netlify?
I'm diving into Node.js and React and decided to play around with an open-source portfolio project I found on GitHub. I forked it, made a few tweaks, and tried to deploy it on Netlify just for kicks. Here's the GitHub link.
However, when I deployed it on [Netlify] , I keep getting a "page not found" error . I believe the main file causing the trouble is App/root.jsx, but I'm having a hard time pinpointing the exact issue.
I'd like to remove Cloudflare from the project if possible.
I know this might be a bit beyond my current skill level, but I'm eager to deploy it just for the fun of it.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
I tried updating netlify.toml but no luck.

First of all run 'npm run build' in cmd,
after it, you will see a new folder named 'dist' inside the folder,
drag and drop that dist folder in netlify to run it as a website.
